# Edit modal scrolls all the way down when it was opened by a link to a scrolled position

Tags: feature-request, bug

When I follow a link to some scrolled position in a thread like this:

[Why does a Ruby program/process spawn more than one thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53932171/why-does-a-ruby-program-process-spawn-more-than-one-thread/53932235?noredirect=1#comment94707161_53932235)

<sup>(The above no longer reproduce the issue, since the post doesn't have a pending edit anymore; but it did at the time of this question being posted).</sup>

and then scroll up to the question position and click on the edit button of the question, then the edit modal appears with the page scrolled all the way down. The black modal covers the whole page, and at first glance, it looks as if something went wrong, and is strange.

I am not sure if this behaviour is intended or not. I think it should better scroll to the top.

Comment: I could repro on Firefox, latest version. Right now the link is no longer useful, since the pending edits were approved and there is no longer a modal dialog if you click on edit.

Comment: I could repro on the latest version of Chrome. You can reproduce the issue by opening a question from the [Suggested Edits](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits) queue and clicking on the timestamps on any comments if they exist (if not, look for another question with suggested edits that have comments), then continuing to click the edit link on the post as described.

Comment: Yep, I went back and was able to reproduce it. FWIW, it also happens if you follow a link to a comment under the question and then attempt to edit an answer way down the page: The modal opens but the page scrolls to the comment so you have to scroll back down.